# Categorical ordinal and dummies

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, ordinal-data

I have a feature categorical ordinal variable (i.e. consumer credit score), that I use to predict a target (i.e., apply for a mortage or not)

I have two options: process it as categorical, or encode as integer.

- Process it as simple categorical variable reduces the predictive potential of the variable, as assumes same distance between categories, but 1 (bad) has much more distance to 6 (good) than to number 2.
- In other hand, if I'm modeling with logistic regression, the coeficients for dummies give a lot more information than the single coefficient if used the var as continuous.

So... what would be the best approach? Use it as categorical o continuous? Or use both, encode as continuous numerical (for better prediction) AND factor the categorical and encode as dummies (for better interpretability)?

If I must, later, predict with other algoritms (like Random Forest, SV, GBM) should I keep both approximations, or keep only one?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Show the freqencies table, as requested:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1353 | 441 | 126 | 77 | 182 | 201 |

Comment: Show a frequency distribution of the score, which will help us to recommend an approach.